# VS 2010 Beta 1 doesn't recognize the System.Printing.PrintTicket class

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I'm having the following problem using the Visual Studio 2010 Team System Beta 1:

While working on some printing code, I tried to declare a variable of type System.Printing.PrintTicket, but Visual Studio doesn't seem to recognize that the class exists. It appears in the MSDN documentation, and other classes like System.Printing.PrintQueue have variables of type PrintTicket, but even in those cases VS doesn't recognize it as a valid type.

Does anyone knows if that is a bug, or am I missing something??

Thanks...

PD: I have the required reference to the System.Printing.dll file in my project and the required 'using' directive in the class file. As a matter of fact, every class of the System.Printing namespace that I've used works, except for that one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I'm definitely an idiot. The problem was that the PrintTicket object is defined in a different assembly than the rest of the System.Printing namespace. I believe that MS should change that but...

Thats it...

Edit: In response to Ivix question, the Assembly where the PrintTicket is defined is ReachFramework  (the filename is ReachFramework.dll)

Answer (score 0):

PrintTicket is a .NET 4.5 function, but the Visual Studio 2010 just support up to .NET 4.0.

If you are using Windows XP, .NET version can only up to be 4.0